# Opening Subl pauses terminal - how do I reset default to -s?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, sublimetext2

So when I open up terminal and run either subl or sublime to open a file, it hangs up the terminal until I close the window.

I've looked around and I understand that its because it automatically calls -wait when I use those commands. I recently did something that allowed me to create an alias for subl -s, but when I restarted my computer it seems to have reverted back.

Would someone be able to help me figure out what files I can go into and change in order reset my default?

Thanks!

(running ubuntu 12.04, sublime text 2)